# Python Selenium Get HTML Text in Variables

Tags: python, selenium

I´m new in the Python Community, so I'm struggling each line of the Script I'm developing.
I will appreciate if any of you can help me with this 'cos I´ve been hours trying to solve it and I can´t.

I want to copy these variables POSIN (from Film), HORROR (from Topic).HTML SOURCE CODE:

```
<div id="text"></div>
<h2 class="form-sign">
<b>DATA</b>
</h2>
<br></br>
<div>
<p>
<b>Film: </b>
POSIN
</p>
<p>
<b>Topic: </b>
HORROR
</p>
</div>
<input name="Description" value="1" type="hidden">
```

I'm using Selenium with python, I´m trying:

```
Film = driver.find_element_by_name("Film")
```

but doesn´t works:

```
NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element: {"method":"name","selector":"Film"}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Film` is not a name. To learn about more that how to locate element refer below link :-

http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/locating-elements.html

For Film use below xpath

```
//p[contains(., 'Film')][1]
```

For Topic use below xpath

```
//p[contains(., 'Topic:')][1]
```

For Film use below code..

```
  movieText =   driver.find_element_by_xpath("//p[contains(., 'Film')][1]")
```

movieText is element you have found

For Topic use below code

```
  movieTopic =  driver.find_element_by_xpath("//p[contains(., 'Topic:')][1]")
```

movieTopic is element you have found

Now to extract text from above element by using below code:-

```
TextOFFilm = movieText.text

TextOFTopix = movieTopic.text
```

`text` is a built-in function which extract text from web element.

Hope it will help you :)

Comment: A million of thanks, thanks to you I can continue. I've been hours and hours and finally I can continue. Thanks!!!

Comment: Welcome @Johnny007 ... I am happy as your problem is resolved :)

Answer (score 1):

"Film" is not name, its text. Name attribute will look like `<b name="Film"> Film: </b>`.

Also, its `Film:`, spaces and unique characters are important when searching. Try this

```
film = driver.find_element_by_xpath(".//b[contains(text(), 'Film')]")
```

And to get the text

```
filmText = film.text
```